# Is cordova platform add ios/android necessary?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I am starting to dig into cordova and using Phonegap-Build to test applications on my iPhone. Since I work in a cloud environment (and dont have a mac), I **cannot** execute the rules to add platforms to my project, ex:

```
cordova platform add ios
cordova platform add android
```

From my understanding you only do this when you want to test it in your web browser, is that correct?
Now I assume that when you use Phonegap-Build, and dont add the platforms to your project, but only install the `/www` folder on your phone (through Build), then everything should work fine... Moreover the platform is already on your phone.

Am I getting this right or does it work otherwise?

Comment: if you use phonegap build, use phonegap CLI, not cordova CLI

Comment: Isnt it interchangeable with cordova since v3? http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/introduction_getting_started.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Build

Comment: cordova.js is interchangeable with phonegap.js, but the CLI is still different, phonegap CLI allow local development and phonegap build development, cordova CLI just local development

Comment: so its like phonegap platform add ios?

Comment: I've tested and you can't add ios from windows even with phonegap CLI. Anyway, you can add this to your config.xml and should add ios on phonegap build <gap:platform name="ios" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You, and many others, seem to have missed the point of Phonegap Build.

You do not need to add ANY platforms on your computer.

Phonegap Build is a cloud service that builds everything for you in the cloud! That is the point. You only need your HTML, JS and CSS (and images). You use the config.xml file to the following things, things you would do in a command line if you were using Phonegap.

- set the platforms you want to build on: iOS, Android, Windows etc.
- choose the plugins you want to use including those that access native features like the camera or geolocation

Read the Phonegap Build docs. It's all in there and its very simple.

The only thing you cannot do, in terms of iOS if you have no Mac, is you cannot actually release your app on the App Store. You can make a working apk and install on an iPhone though.

Comment: Thats it! Btw, if you have some sample apps or tutorials worth considering let us know. Thank you

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification, sometimes with people not having English as a first language it is difficult to tell whether it is a grammar problem or (in this case, amusingly) a proper noun

Comment: I think there are some sample phonegap build apps on the net. Google them. If you want a really simple example use the docs and build a one page app with jQuery Mobile. It's not the best framework to use but it'll let you see a working example.